# Keep only the largest cluster of non-zero pixels on binary image

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

I would like to remove all of the smaller non-zero pixel clusters and only leave the largest. The largest cluster could be located anywhere on the image and any shape. My thought are looping over the image and couting all of the pixel value that are 1 if they have a neighbour with a non-zero value too and assinging this to a cluster, then keeping the cluster with the largest nunber. However, this seems very computionally heavy and was hoping for a better approach. I have attached an image sample below:

[image]

Comment: Do you prefer to solve this yourself or are you just interested in detecting the cluster? If the latter is the case you should have a look at [blob detection](https://learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/), because it a) is able to detect clusters and b) provides options so filter according to cluster properties (e.g. size, shape...)

Comment: Just interested in detecting the cluster. I will look into the blob detection, thank you.

Comment: “Blob analysis” is called “Connected Component Analysis” in the literature, and often referred to simply as “labeling”. It is trivial to keep track of sizes while doing the labeling. Some implementations have an option to keep only the largest component. For example [this one](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/regions.html#dip-Label-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-uint--dip-uint--dip-uint--dip-StringArray--dip-String-CL).

Comment: I found using the cv2 findCountours method, then sorting and using index 0 for the largest to be a good solution. Thanks for your help